# Non-EEA Family Member of EEA Citizen Traveling to UK

Tags: visas, paperwork, italy, family

I am italian going back to uk, checking on gov.uk it seems that she can come with me, she need article 10 residency card, what is it? Is possible for her to come with me in uk at the same time? She has the long term living permit in italy. Regards

Comment: What's the purpose of your trip?  Is your family member a " visa national" for short visits to the UK (that is, would she need a standard visitor visa to visit the UK without you)?  What is her relationship to you?

Answer (score 1):

A valid Article 10 (or Article 20) residence card allows the non-EEA national family member of an EEA citizen to travel to the UK without the requirement to obtain an EEA or EUSS family permit.

If you’re travelling to the UK together, she should have the following in addition to the valid residence card:

- valid passport
- evidence that she is the family member of an EEA citizen (for example, your marriage certificate or birth certificate)

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

Answer (score 0):

You ask

> What is an article 10 card?

The term *Article 10 card,* first of all, often includes cards issued under article 20 of the free movement directive as well as those issued under article 10.  Cards issued by Italy under article 10 say *Carta di soggiorno di familiare di un cittadino dell'Unione.*  Cards issued under article 20 will have the word *permanente* added to that.

> Is possible for her to come with me in uk at the same time?

Yes.  If she is a "non-visa national" who is visa exempt for short visits to the US, she needs only her passport and proof of relationship to you, as noted in Traveller's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/154592/19400).  If she is a "visa national," then she needs either:

- an article 10 card, or
- an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit) (EEA FP), or
- an [EU Settlement Scheme family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eu-settlement-scheme-family-permit) (EUSS FP).

If her card is not an article 10 card, she should get an EUSS FP if you are registered with the EU Settlement Scheme, or an EEA FP if you are not.